# What could this sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Did you notice the view?

This is the example sentence of "notice" in my dictionary.

But I don't know what that means.

"Did you notice the point?" or "Did you see the view?"

Could you give me the exact meaning of it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any more context for this?

Comment: But the dictionary would have also provided a definition. Was the definition of *notice* unclear? And if you understand both *Did you notice the point?* and *Did you see the view?*, I don't know why *Did you notice the view?* isn't clear.

Comment: It's a very strange "example usage", so I suggest you consider carefully whether you should get yourself a different dictionary. Note that by default ***the view*** in such a context would normally mean the entire "panorama, vista" (of the landscape, for example) visible from some particular location It's hard to imagine someone being in a position where there's an impressive "view" and ***not*** seeing it. So it would be extremely weird to ask if someone ***noticed*** it - a bit like asking someone who went to the beach ***Did you notice the sea?*** (or ***the sand***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Notice' in this context means more than 'see'; it means 'pay particular attention to'. The question 'Did you notice the view?' might have been asked by Sherlock Holmes before he points out that the view (normally a beautiful but unimportant feature) actually reveals that ...

So, your dictionary might have chosen a clearer  example of the usage of the word notice, because that example raised more questions than it answers.

It is reported that when Margaret Thatcher was Prime Minster of Great Britain her secretary was instructed to ask the Queen what colour dress she would be wearing at some event they were both due to attend, so as to avoid a clash. The answer, which counts as a brilliant put-down that is not actually rude was: "The Queen does not notice what other people wear".

Answer (score 0):

As an elaboration on @FumbleFingers, try breaking the sentence down. What is each word in the sentence doing?

> Did you notice the view?

Here, someone is asking a question to someone else about if they've seen "the view," which is used as a noun. A view, from the verb view, is something that you see, usually a landscape, or something that you believe, like a political view. Here, *to notice* (used as a verb) means *to see* or *to experience.*
Thus, this sentence means something like "Did you see the landscape?" Imagine if you visit a cliff and someone says, "Look at that sky! Did you notice the view?"